# Get the URL path without the params

Tags: angularjs, routes

**Goal**:
The main idea is about getting $location.path() without the `:param` that set in the route provider.

**Description**:
Assume that my app has to define randomly paths with one param.
So I'll use loop function to define all of them for clean code and DRY issue.

For example:

```
// get pool of paths from server and set them dynamically
pathsApi.get().then(function(res){
   // just example for demonstrate
   res.data = ['search1','search2','search3','search4'];
   angular.forEach(res.data, function(route,key){
      .when('/search/' + route + '/:search', route.resolve('Search', '/', 'svm'));
   });
});

// other regular paths
.when('/home', route.resolve('Home', '/', 'hvm'));
.when('/help', route.resolve('Help', '/', 'hlvm'));
```

Grat. Everything works fine. now i have a lot of paths i can access.

**Problem / Advice I need**:
I have a directive that do some things.
One of them is to check if the location contain the word search, and if it is, I want to get the name of the route of the search.

For example:

The user go to `/#/search/search3/someText`.
I want to get `/#/search/search3`.

Of course I can use split and other techniques. But I know that angular knows that `someText` is a param (which is called `:search`).
So I'm sure that angular can tell me what is the $location.$path without the `:search` so it will be only the path like I mentioned before.

I'm looking for elegant way through angular without the messy code, splits or assumptions.
I don't want to use $location.search or $location.hash instead. I want to save the URL scheme as is.

Comment: problem becomes trivial if you switch to angular-ui router which is far more robust than ngRoute

Answer (score 0):

I found two possible quick solutions, it depends if you like it or not.

I've used **angular-ui-router**.

The first one is to create a routes.json file where you can store all your routes and then get the json synchronously before the app runs and store all routes inside the $rootScope so you can easily access them wherever.
With this solution you will always have the clear path stored in the json.

```
var routes;

$.ajax({
    url : 'routes.json',
    method : 'GET',
    dataType : 'json',
    async : false
}).success(function(response){
    routes = response;
});

// Routes
var Settings = function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

    $stateProvider
        .state(routes.HOME.name, {
            url : routes.HOME.path
        })
        .state(routes.SEARCH.name, {
            url : routes.SEARCH.path + '/' + routes.SEARCH.params
        });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

};

Settings.$inject = [
    '$stateProvider',
    '$urlRouterProvider'
];

app.config(Settings);
```

**route.json**

```
{
    "HOME" : { "name" : "home", "path" : "/" },
    "SEARCH" : { "name" : "search", "path" : "/search", "params" : ":params" }
}
```

---

The second one, because there's no direct parameter that can tell you the clear path, you can use the $state.current.url which tells you the current url with all params as you typed inside in the $stateProvider configuration: like :param or :search

Then you can use $stateParams to know which parameters you have set and remove it with a string replace.

Maybe could help you

```
// Routes
var Settings = function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url : '/',
            template : 'home page'
        })
        .state('search', {
            url : '/search/:param',
            controller : 'SearchCtrl'
        });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

};

Settings.$inject = [
    '$stateProvider',
    '$urlRouterProvider'
];

app.config(Settings);
```

---

```
// Controller
var SearchCtrl = function($scope, $state, $stateParams){

    // Parameters 
    var cleanPath;

    // Methods
    function initCtrl(){

        cleanPath = getCleanUrlPath($state.current.url, $stateParams);  

    }   

    function getCleanUrlPath(url, params){

        for( var param in params) {
            // Remove from the url all params inside $stateParams
            url = url.replace(':' + param, '');
        }

        return url;

    }

    // Initialize controller
    initCtrl();

};

SearchCtrl.$inject = [
    '$scope',
    '$state',
    '$stateParams'
];

app.controller('SearchCtrl', SearchCtrl);
```

Comment: I thought about your seconds idea. It's a little problematic in cases of url like this:
`help/programs/help+me+to+understand`

Replace won't work as expected in case that the word is `help` and may be a little buggy in some cases.

Comment: the replace will work only on the parameters written in the state, not in the query string itself. For example if you set "search/:param" the replace won't deal with the string interpolated in the URL but with ":param".

Comment: I'm using the built in `ngRoute` angular lib.
Your answer based on `angular-ui router`?

Comment: yes, it is written in the second row. I've added that after the answer :)